# Email signature auto adjustable roundcube details

Tags: html, html-email, email

I’m using this technique for email signature:

[How to make responsive signature mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398137/how-to-make-responsive-signature-mail)

Is working perfect and all if I execute a .html in a browser, but if I go to roundcube and I copy the html, it displays both the wide and narrow versions, it doesn’t hide one as happens when you run the html in a browser. How do could you fix this to make auto adjustable in html, of roundcube or others?

Comment: Please add your code so someone can have a look.

Comment: the code is identical to the link I post.

Comment: I would suggest reading the how to guide. Questions like this get flagged too quickly